# Why can't i set the visibility of my images in android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

my APP should show and/or hide images according to some variables. Here's the code:

```
final ImageView greenSquare = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.greensquare);
final ImageView greenBigSquare = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.greenBIGsquare);

if (a) {
    if (b) {
        b = false;
        a = false;
        greenSquare.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        greenBigSquare.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        b = true;
    }
} else {
    if (c) {
        a = !a;
        greenSquare.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        greenBigSquare.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}
```

And here's the XML

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/greenBIGsquare"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    opencv:srcCompat="@color/colorFollowMe" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/greensquare"
    android:visibility="visible"
    opencv:srcCompat="@color/colorAccent" />
```

but it doesn't run correctly and it crushes.

Here's the logcat

> 01-29 20:20:18.487 6535-6667/pinwheel.redblock E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: Thread-331
>                                                                    Process: pinwheel.redblock, PID: 6535
>                                                                    android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the
>   original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
>                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:6556)
>                                                                        at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:942)
>                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:5081)
>                                                                        at android.view.View.invalidateInternal(View.java:12719)
>                                                                        at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:12683)
>                                                                        at android.view.View.setFlags(View.java:10640)
>                                                                        at android.view.View.setVisibility(View.java:7431)
>                                                                        at android.widget.ImageView.setVisibility(ImageView.java:1469)
>                                                                        at
>   pinwheel.redblock.MainActivity_Show_camera.onCameraFrame(MainActivity_Show_camera.java:492)
>                                                                        at
>   org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.deliverAndDrawFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.java:391)
>                                                                        at
>   pinwheel.redblock.PortraitCameraView.access$400(PortraitCameraView.java:21)
>                                                                        at
>   pinwheel.redblock.PortraitCameraView$CameraWorker.run(PortraitCameraView.java:289)
>                                                                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

Can anybody help me? Thank you

Comment: Post your logcat of the crash

Comment: Post the exception log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {

        greenSquare.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        greenBigSquare.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }
});
```

also use this in your else block during changing the visibility..

any action involving the user interface must be done in the main or UI thread

Answer (score 0):

Try annotating the method with `@UiThread`